# Views on Inter-Faith Dialogue and using other Religious Literature

Tags: scripture, dharma, non-hindu, comparitive-theology, restrictions

I was looking at Francais Clooney's comparative theology and I liked his view. From what I got he held that other religious texts could give a new perspective of your religion and welcome them, but not necessarily treat them the same as scripture. I am not seeking validation of other faiths or other literature at all. But, even from natural science, I have tried to compare Ramunaja's doctrine to the human body and its functions. I am wondering what the traditional faith stance is on not treating other religious or even just non-religious literature as scripture, but rather as a use of inspiration to see a newer perspective of your tradition. I know many texts discourage the speaking, reading, or following of Nastika's text, but is this based on more of the fact that they claim to be scripture, can one take inspiration from them to find a new view of one's faith? Another addition to this question is can other literature not connected with religion unintentionally has a partial, but not whole truth of our faith and way to salvation. Again I am not seeking validation I am a staunch Vaishnava and believe only through Vishnu is salvation achieved, but the field of comparative theology is not to be confused with the heretical concept of syncretism unless sanctioned by scripture ie a Buddha is Vishnu avatar. The answer should address Nastika, Forgien, and general Literature. Proper sources are required and hopefully, they directly address the topic.

Comment: This is a forum on Hinduism only. It is not a forum for comparing other religious traditions with Hinduism. It is also not appropriate to ask questions that ask for opinions. Please read forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, but this question is related to Hinduism and what Hindu scriptures think of comparitive theology and using other literatures for inspiration not just other religious ones, but even general human compisitions.

Comment: This is a good question actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
can one take inspiration from them to find a new view of one's faith?
```

Yes but with limitations

Quoting from Yoga vasistha 2.18

> verse 2
> **Even human compositions are acceptable when they are instructive of good sense**; otherwise the Vedas also are to be renounced (as
> unreliable); because men are required always to abide by reason.
>
> verse 3
> **Words conformable with reason are to be received even if spoken by boys; otherwise they are to be rejected as straws though pronounced by
> the lotus-born (Brahma himself).**

*So, you can accept verses of bravery, morality but you must never have notions  different on life (described in scripture), rebirth , God(parambrahm parmeshwar) and holy vedas*

Personally, I like this verse even though I hate Bible idea of going to hell eternally

*Psalm 23:4
Even though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil, for you are with me; your rod and your staff, they comfort me.*

Manusmriti ch 12

> पितृदेवमनुष्याणां वेदश्चक्षुः सनातनम् ।
>
> अशक्यं चाप्रमेयं च वेदशास्त्रमिति स्थितिः ॥
>
> या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः।
>
> सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः॥
>
> उत्पद्यन्ते च्यवन्ते च यान्यतोऽन्यानि कानि चित् ।
>
> तान्यर्वाक्कालिकतया निष्फलान्यनृतानि च ॥
>
> For Pitṛs, gods and men, the Veda is the eternal eye; the teaching of
> the Veda is beyond power and illimitable. Such is the settled
> fact.—(94)
>
> Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
> false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection; as they
> have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—(95)
>
> Those other (doctrines) which spring up and perish are all worthless
> and false, being of modern growth.—(96)

For other question about liberation of non hindus :
[Already answered](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44297/is-it-possible-for-a-non-hindu-who-rejects-the-teaching-of-vedas-and-gita-attain)

On Athiest and foreign literature

According to medhatti manubhasya of manusmriti 11.65. you must avoid books ridiculing God or denying existence of paramaatma

> अनाहिताग्निता स्तेयं ऋणानामनपक्रिया ।
>
> असत्शास्त्राधिगमनं कौशीलव्यस्य च क्रिया ॥ ६५ ॥
>
> Omission of fire-laying, theft, non-payment of debts, studying bad
> books, and the practising of the histrionic art.—(65)
> *(These come under minor offence)*
> Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):
>
> ‘Bad books’—e.g., those written by Cārvākas and Nirgranthas; those
> that are not trustworthy, and have no connection with Vedic rites or
> their effects.

For foreign literature, I think you must decide yourself

> BG 18.63: Thus, I have explained to you this knowledge that is more
> secret than all secrets. Ponder over it deeply, and then do as you
> wish.
>
> nahin anīti nahin kachhu prabhutāī, sunahu karahu jo tumhahi sohāī
> (Ramayan) [v35]
>
> “The advice I have given to you is neither incorrect nor coercive.
> Listen to it carefully, contemplate over it, and then do what you
> wish.”